# How to Periodically delete data in Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am ingesting data into an Azure SQL database using stream analytics while connecting to an event hub. What I am trying to do is periodically delete data from my tables so that I only maintain a certain amount of days stored. Ex: 30 days.

I have been trying to track down a method of periodically executing the required T-SQL against my database and have found Azure Elastic jobs as a solution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-jobs-tsql-create-manage

Is this the best method to periodically delete rows from an azure SQL database?

Comment: Maybe an Azure Data  Factory set to run on whatever schedule you want.

Comment: Hi @TsSkTo, If the answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create stored procedure to delete the data in table.

There are many ways can achieve that.

1. In Data Factory, create a pipeline to call the delete stored procedure with a time trigger: every month:
   [image]
2. With Logic app, create a Recurrence trigger to  call the delete stored procedure:
   [image]
3. You could try the Azure Elastic jobs you found.

Just choose the way which you think it's most easiest for you, I think that's the best method for you to periodically delete rows from an azure SQL database.

Comment: The logic app was the way to go. Simple and visual. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Temporal Tables have a retention period.  Please consider this if it works for your use case.  Otherwise you can use a job framework to delete old data once a day like you mention.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Azure Automation to run a stored procedure that will do the clean up. You can run the following PowerShell on a RunBook (Azure Automation).

```
$sqlSvrName=“DBServerName"

$sqlDbName=“DatabaseName"

$sqlUserName=“DatabaseUserName"

$sqlPassword=“DatabaseUserPassword"

$sqlStoredProcedure=“StoredProcedureName"

 

$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = “Server=$sqlSvrName;uid=$sqlUserName;pwd=$sqlPassword;Initial Catalog=$sqlDbName“

$startDateTime = Get-Date

$sqlConnection.Open()

 

select $sqlConnection.ConnectionString

 

$sqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

# specify that command is a stored procedure

$sqlCmd.CommandType=[System.Data.CommandType]'StoredProcedure'

# specify the name of the stored procedure

$sqlCmd.CommandText = $sqlStoredProcedure

$sqlCmd.Connection = $sqlConnection 

#————- specify optional parameters to stored procedure

#$startDateTime=$sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(“@rundatetime" , [System.Data.SqlDbType]::DateTime)

$startDateTime = Get-Date

 $sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

To know the complete set of steps to do this on Azure Automation, please read [here](https://www.advaiya.com/blog/creating-a-schedule-to-run-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-powershell-script-using-azure-automation/#:%7E:text=%20Creating%20a%20schedule%20to%20run%20a%20SQL,Step%203.%20PowerShell%20Script%20.%20%20More%20).